# After Jetty Update to 9.4.x: Missing Constraint: Require-Capability: osgi.extender; filter:="(osgi.extender=osgi.serviceloader.processor)"

Tags: eclipse, jetty, osgi, jetty-9

After updating from Jetty 9.3.x to 9.4.x I'm getting the following validate message when I launch my **OSGi Framework** launch:

```
Missing Constraint: Require-Capability: osgi.extender; filter:="(osgi.extender=osgi.serviceloader.processor)"
Missing Constraint: Require-Capability: osgi.extender; filter:="(osgi.extender=osgi.serviceloader.registrar)"
```

[image]

I can't figure out the bundles I have to add?

Already included in the launch (among many others):

- `org.eclipse.jetty.client`
- `org.eclipse.jetty.continuation`
- `org.eclipse.jetty.deploy`
- `org.eclipse.jetty.http`
- `org.eclipse.jetty.io`
- `org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite`
- `org.eclipse.jetty.security`
- `org.eclipse.jetty.server`
- `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet`
- `org.eclipse.jetty.servlets`
- `org.eclipse.jetty.util`
- `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp`
- `org.eclipse.jetty.xml`
- `org.eclipse.osgi`
- `org.eclipse.osgi.services`
- `org.eclipse.osgi.util`

The server launches without error messages after clicking "OK" in the dialog.
I hoped this issue would be fixed in Jetty 9.4.5 but it remains.

Comment: This is due to the increased reliance on `java.util.ServiceLoader` within many of the specs that Jetty relies on (outside of OSGi).

Comment: `java.util.ServiceLoader` is part of the JRE 1.8, why do I get a validation error?

Comment: See http://blog.osgi.org/2013/02/javautilserviceloader-in-osgi.html

Comment: Thanks for the link got it fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to download and add the following three bundles to the target:

- [org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle%22)
- [org.apache.aries.util](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/aries/org.apache.aries.util/1.1.1/org.apache.aries.util-1.1.1.jar)
- [asm-all](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-all/5.0.4/asm-all-5.0.4.jar)

As described on the [Apache Aries SPI Fly](https://aries.apache.org/modules/spi-fly.html) website, section **Getting SPI Fly**.

Since I do not want to manipulate the bytecode I choose "**For use with dynamic weaving**".

More information on the topic can be found in this [blog](https://blog.osgi.org/2013/02/javautilserviceloader-in-osgi.html).

Answer (score 4):

It appears you need an implementation of the OSGi Service Loader Mediator specification. Try Apache Aries SPI Fly.